# Why won't jQuery call my Ajax error handler?

Tags: ajax, jquery, error-handling

I have the following jQuery Ajax call (There are no other global settings/handlers):

```
$.ajax( { 
   url: "http://www.blah.com/url/does/not/exist", 
   type: "get",
   data: someData,
   dataType: "json",
   error: function (xhr, msg, ex)
   {
       alert("Failed: " + msg);
   },
   complete: function (xhr, msg)
   {
       alert("Done: " + msg);
   }
```

I would expect my error handler to be called, but instead the `complete` event fires and the alert displays `Done: success`. In my Javascript console, I see the following message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.blah.com/url/does/not/exist. 
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

1. Why won't my error handler get called?
2. What is the meaning of the `Origin` message logged to the console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the only way is to receive the server response in my `success` method and store it in a global variable, which I'll check in the handler for `complete` (which always gets called).  No response means the request failed.

It's a shoddy way of handling errors in this otherwise excellent libary.

Answer (score 1):

Your error handler isn't called because the AJAX request doesn't even take place: the browser refuses to do that because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy): the data you're requesting would come from a different site than the one serving your page.

You can try using the `JSONP` data type to work around the problem:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://www.blah.com/url/does/not/exist", 
    type: "get",
    data: someData,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    error: function(xhr, msg, ex) {
        alert("Failed: " + msg);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, msg) {
       alert("Done: " + msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: I cheered too soon... Now neither `success` nor `error` is called, and the console displays: `Failed to load resource` -- any ideas?

Comment: Well, `Failed to load resource` is your `404` error. That means the error handler is only called when the web server actually processes the request. In other words, it will only be called for `5xx` errors, not 4xx errors, so it won't be called if the page doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I wonder what's the point of having an error handler if it doesn't catch all errors?  The most likely error that I will need to handle is a network problem (no connection), which produces a 404...