# error and succes callback in jQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

With fallowing ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    error: error,
    success: success
)}
```

Is it possible that none of error, success will be called. If yes in what kind of situations it happens?

I ask because from server logs is suspect error is not called on some kind of errors(connection problems? maybe), but I can't reproduce this situation locally.

Comment: what exactly do you mean?? difficult to understand your line "Is it possible that none of error, success will be called. If yes in what kind of situations it happens?"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently neither `success` nor `error` would be called if a JSONP request fails. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **`error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`**
>   Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests.

But since your call does not seem to be of this nature, I'd say either one gets called every time.

Comment: Then either once gets called every time, afaik.

Comment: I want to be sure if error always will be called if something goes wrong

Comment: That might depend on what can go wrong, which depends on your application. I suggest you try some failure scenarios and see for yourself.

Comment: I asked because of this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407430/why-wont-jquery-call-my-ajax-error-handler) I started to doubt it is working I expected.

Comment: That's a cross domain request, for which `error` is not executed, as I cited in my answer.